# Open jQuery Accordion from TamperMonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have an accordion on a page looking like this,

```
<div class="acc-header ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-corner-all" action="stockexchange.php?ajax=true&amp;step=profile&amp;ID=5" role="tab" id="ui-accordion-1-header-26" aria-controls="ui-accordion-1-panel-26" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
            <div class="logo-stock">
                <i class="stock-iou-icon"></i>
                <!-- <img width="80px" height="60px" src="/images/v2/stock/portfolio_logos/IOU_logo.png?v=1486475443550" /> -->
            </div>
            <div class="abbr-name d-hide" title="Insured On Us">IOU</div>
            <div class="name t-overflow">Insured On Us</div>
            <div class="change down">
                <i class="arrow-change-icon" role="img" aria-label="stock price is down"></i>
                <span class="value">
                    $0.015                    </span>
            </div>
            <div class="arrow-left">
                <div class="t-delimiter d-hide"></div>
                <div class="b-delimiter d-hide"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="wai t-wai-reset">Stock Price: </span>
                $148.33                </div>
            <div class="owned">
                <span class="wai t-wai-reset">Owned: </span>
                0                </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

and I need to open this using a TamperMonkey script from a separate page. I basically need to simulate clicking on it automatically, however I'm unsure on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use a jQuery code like the one from below:

```js
$(".acc-header").click(function(){
  //hiding content from id ->content
  $("#content").slideToggle();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="acc-header">
  Click this header!
 </h1>

<div id="content">
This text will hide!
</div>
```

You click on the header, then content is hidden.

Comment: Right, but I need to do this from a script, without manually clicking it. I'm not sure how to simulate the click itself in the script to get the data.

Comment: Normally you can do this with a code like this one:
`$(".acc-header").trigger("click");`